# CSS Flexbox Wrap First of Line

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm struggling with the wrapping option of the css flexbox in combination with margins between the items.

What I'm trying to archieve is: Have a flexcontainer with wrapping enabled and a number of items with variable with and minimum width. Between these items I want to have a small gap (margin) but I don't want a margin between the item and the container on the left or right side.

Right now I'm using the first-child and last-child pseudo class but this approach doesn't work unfortunatly when the container wraps the content. See [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xw5uo2j1/9/) for a minimalistic demo.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">A</div>
    <div class="item">B</div>
    <div class="item">C</div>
    <div class="item">D</div>
    <div class="item">E</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.item {
    min-width: 100px;
    flex: 1;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.item:first-child {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.item:last-child {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

flexbox has some specific properties, so in your case this is what needs to be fixed:

- instead of `min-width` use `flex-basis`
- use `justify-content: space-between`
- to apply margin on items there's a special hack (check out the
  example -to fix border coherency apply a wrapper);

```css
.container-bg {
    width:100%;
    border: 1px solid green;
    overflow:hidden;
    
}
 .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
   /* border: 1px solid red;*/
    margin: 0 -20px;
}
.item {
    /*min-width: 100px;*/
    flex: 1 0 100px;/*if you want to set 100px as min-width you'll have to set flex-shrink to 0*/
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0 20px;
}
/*.item:first-child {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.item:last-child {
    margin-right: 0px;
}*/
```

```html
<p>resize the window for wrapping</p>
<div class="container-bg"><div class="container">
    <div class="item">A</div>
    <div class="item">B</div>
    <div class="item">C</div>
    <div class="item">D</div>
    <div class="item">E</div>
</div></div>
```

EDIT :

set `flex-shrink` to 0 is don't want to go below a certain width..

Comment: Seems to be a preety straightforward way of doing this. Just one issue: the negative margin on the container causes scrollbars because of the extra space. How would I cope with this? See updated Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xw5uo2j1/12/

Comment: Just found out myself: apply overflow: hidden to the wrapper - https://jsfiddle.net/xw5uo2j1/14/

Answer (score 0):

If you add another wrapper around your items, you can use this *dirty* hack: https://jsfiddle.net/xw5uo2j1/13/

You set your main container to be 100% of the width, then your "sub" container to be 100% plus the amount of space between you're going to add. Then add the same amount of `margin-right` to the items.

```css
.maincontainer {
    width:100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content:space-between;
    align-content:space-between;
    width:calc(100% + 5px);
}
.item {
    min-width: 100px;
    flex: 1;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<p>resize the window for wrapping</p>
<div class="maincontainer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item">A</div>
        <div class="item">B</div>
        <div class="item">C</div>
        <div class="item">D</div>
        <div class="item">E</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Jamie, thank you for your efforts. Is there any benefit in using a calculated width for the container over the negative margin solution from maioman?

Comment: @kai personally I would choose most solutions over a negative margin. They have a nasty tendency to cause issues further on down the line. For example applying `overflow:hidden;` really only puts a blanket over an underlying issue, rather than fixing it. Of course the problem with my solution is that you need two containers. I'll leave it up to you to decide which is best **for you**. I went this way because it meant the red border surrounding it is flush.

Comment: @kai I would also note that swapping `min-width:100px;` with `flex: 1 1 100px;` actually means the widths go below this when the total width is less than 100px. Personally I think this is a good thing and would suggest you use it, however it depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED, with more than 5 items

Use `calc` and `jusify-content: space-between;`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  border: thin solid red;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 -10px;
}

.item {
  border: thin solid black;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 calc(20% - 20px);
  flex: 1 1 calc(20% - 20px);
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">A</div>
    <div class="item">B</div>
    <div class="item">C</div>
    <div class="item">D</div>
    <div class="item">E</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm assuming this will only work if you implicitly have five items?

Comment: The first solution.. yep. Updated the sample for more than 5 items. If there are less than 5 items per row, the items grow. If you want to stay with fixed widths just change to 'flex: 0 0 calc(20% - 20px);'